# Difficulties with deploying Discord music bot to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I was trying to make a Discord music bot and deploy it to Heroku, I tried to use the play command

```
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
        'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    if not get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild).is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['url']
        get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild).play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild).is_playing()
        await ctx.send('Bot is playing')
```

but got the error message from Heroku:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug
```

I have tried to reinstall youtube-dl but it didn't work.

If you can help me, that would be great!
Thanks.

Comment: Does it only fail in heroku, or also on your own machine? Can you download the videos (with the same options) from a clean python script and/or the command line?

Comment: It works perfectly fine if I host the bot myself.

Comment: It could be some kind of heroku thing blocking access to youtube downloader (it makes sense, given that they are a company). Are you able to run the same downloads from a command line?

Comment: Yes, I was able to download a video using Heroku's console with youtube-dl.

Comment: Does it always fail on a single video, or all of them? Can you download other videos (both from the command line or inside of discordpy)?

Comment: Yes it fails on every video if I use the play function but using the command line downloads it just fine.

Comment: No video formats found can be caused by many errors. Check the logs and inform which error code is being raised. For example, if the code is 429, the API is rate limiting.

Answer (score 0):

**This error is coming for that you are using YTDL, and ytdl is now old and the api of ytdl is so old so if you want to make a good music bot for production then use Lavalink**

****Best Wrappesrs For Lavalink****

- Wavelink
- Pomice
- Lavalink
- Lavasnek_rs

If you want to install these packages just use pip install< Wrappers name >

****If you facing any error feel free to join [Help server](https://discord.gg/9tr4EtEbdH)****